# Can I compare vector objects to NULL?

Tags: c++, vector, null, comparison

I come from Python/Java land and I'm trying to tinker with making my own hashmap now in c++.

When I try to check to compare the locations of positions in the hash table to NULL (lines 6 and 11), I get the error:

```
invalid operands to binary expression ('value_type' (aka 'HashEntry') and 'long')"
```

I'm hoping someone can steer me in the direction of what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it.

```
void CustomHash::insert(HashEntry entry) {
    int k = entry.getKey();
    int i = 0;
    int hashVal = hash_One(k);
    int temp = hashVal;
    while (i < size && hashArray[temp] != NULL) {
        i++;
        temp = (hashVal + i*hash_Two(k)) % size;
    }

    if (hashArray[temp] == NULL) {
        hashArray[temp] = entry;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Failure" << endl;
    }
}
```

Edit 1: hashArray declaration

```
CustomHash::CustomHash(int m) {
    this->size = m;
    this->hashArray = vector<HashEntry>();
}
```

Comment: The compiler tells you that it is an error. If you show the declaration of `hasArray`, someone might be able to offer a solution.

Comment: `hashArray.count(temp)`

Comment: @Justin André is writing his own hash map as an exercise. It's reasonable to assume that `hashArray` is of that type and not the standard hash map. As such, you can't assume it has the `count` method.

Comment: Don't use `NULL` in modern C++ - we have `nullptr` now.

Comment: @RSahu hashArray is a vector<HashEntry> Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given,

> hashArray is a `vector<HashEntry>` Object

`hashArray[temp]` evaluates to a `HashEntry`. You cannot compare a `HashEntry` with `NULL`.

Use a different strategy to check whether `hasArray` has any items whose key is equal to `temp`. I suggest using [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count).

```
while (i < size && std::count_if(hashArray.begin(), hashArray.end(),
                                 [=temp](HashEntry const& e)
                                 { return (temp == e.getKey());}) > 0 )
{
    i++;
    temp = (hashVal + i*hash_Two(k)) % size;
}
```

A better solution, as suggested by @cdhowie, is to use [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

```
while (i < size && std::any_of(hashArray.begin(), hashArray.end(),
                               [=temp](HashEntry const& e)
                               { return (temp == e.getKey());}) )
{
    i++;
    temp = (hashVal + i*hash_Two(k)) % size;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest `std::any_of` over `std::count_if` since the condition is `> 0` -- we can stop early if we find a match.

Comment: @cdhowie, Thanks. It's a better solution.